# PHP array splice not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode, splice

I'm trying to build a shortcode in wp that displays data from 2 RSS feeds.

The problem is that I can't limit the number of items in array. I tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028883/limit-the-number-of-rss-feed-to-fetch) and none worked.

```
function rss_posts_func( $atts ){
    $feed = fetch_feed(array('rss-feed-1', 'rss-feed-2'));
    $feed = array();
    $feed = array_splice($feed, 0, 3);
    // Loop the results
     $content = '<ul class="rss-aggregator">';
    foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
        $content .= '<li class="feed-item">';
        $content .= '<a href='.$item->get_permalink().'>';
        $content .= $item->get_title();
        $content .= '</a></li>';
    }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Remove line number 3: `$feed = array();`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat That still doesn't work.

Comment: Line #3 is just negating all you did at Line #2. You're splicing an empty array. Also the reason why it still didn't work after removing Line #3 is because [fetch_feed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/#return) is returning an `object` and not an `array`.

Comment: So how I can limit that to 3 results?

Comment: Can you var_dump the array so that we can see it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
function rss_posts_func( $atts ){
    $i = 1;
    $feed = fetch_feed(array('rss-feed-1', 'rss-feed-2'));
     $content = '<ul class="rss-aggregator">';
    foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
        $content .= '<li class="feed-item">';
        $content .= '<a href='.$item->get_permalink().'>';
        $content .= $item->get_title();
        $content .= '</a></li>';
        if($i++ == 8) break;
    }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm the OP. I added an increment into the foreach and when it hits the desired value, break the loop. Thanks.